# Shell script awk concatenate text with entire column

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk

I have a csv file Final.csv and i am trying to change its first coulmn and add a text it each column row
like this is the csv

```
Trialtime   type    Track   time    Notes   Athlete
07:15:00    Warmup  ABC 85.2    Initial warmup  Jon
07:45:00    Sprint1 ABC 59.44   First Sprint    Jon
08:30:00    TRIAL   ABC 57.21   Final attempt   Jon
08:00:00    Warmup  ABC 120.51  Initial warmup  Bill
08:40:05    Sprint1 ABC 61.35   First Sprint    Bill
09:15:00    Sprint2 ABC 60.08   Second Sprint   Bill
10:30:00    TRIAL   ABC 60.37   Final attempt   Bill
```

and i want to add a text to the trial time coulmn like this

```
Trialtime   type    Track   time    Notes   Athlete
2012 07:15:00   Warmup  ABC 85.2    Initial warmup  Jon
2012 07:45:00   Sprint1 ABC 59.44   First Sprint    Jon
2012 08:30:00   TRIAL   ABC 57.21   Final attempt   Jon
2012 08:00:00   Warmup  ABC 120.51  Initial warmup  Bill
2012 08:40:05   Sprint1 ABC 61.35   First Sprint    Bill
2012 09:15:00   Sprint2 ABC 60.08   Second Sprint   Bill
2012 10:30:00   TRIAL   ABC 60.37   Final attempt   Bill
```

i try to print each line row in that coulmn like this with awk

```
awk -F',' 'NR>1{print $1}1' OFS=',' $OutFileName
```

NR>1 is for not including the headers
but i want to add a text variable to each row in the coulmn

lets say

```
text="2012"
```

now i want to modify the trial time column rows with this 2012 appended to each row
what i wa doing was

```
awk -F',' 'NR>1{$1$text;}1' OFS=',' $OutFileName
```

but the text variable does not work inside awk what to do ?
**and i also want to keep the headers.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -v t="2012" 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }NR>1{ $1=t" "$1 }1' file
```

The output:

```
Trialtime   type    Track   time    Notes   Athlete
2012 07:15:00    Warmup  ABC 85.2    Initial warmup  Jon
2012 07:45:00    Sprint1 ABC 59.44   First Sprint    Jon
2012 08:30:00    TRIAL   ABC 57.21   Final attempt   Jon
2012 08:00:00    Warmup  ABC 120.51  Initial warmup  Bill
2012 08:40:05    Sprint1 ABC 61.35   First Sprint    Bill
2012 09:15:00    Sprint2 ABC 60.08   Second Sprint   Bill
2012 10:30:00    TRIAL   ABC 60.37   Final attempt   Bill
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -v txt="2012" 'NR==1||$0=txt FS $0' yourFile
```

For the input and output example, this will do what you want.